# Discord API v13 Error: ReferenceError: message is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I was making a purge command delete all channels and ended up running into the error:

```
C:\Users\zaned\Desktop\bot\main.js:13
    message.guild.channels.forEach(channel => channel.delete())
    ^

ReferenceError: message is not defined
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\zaned\Desktop\bot\main.js:13:5)
    at Client.emit (node:events:390:28)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\zaned\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:25:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\zaned\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\zaned\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:350:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\zaned\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:443:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\zaned\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:300:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\zaned\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:199:18)
    at WebSocket.emit (node:events:390:28)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (C:\Users\zaned\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:1022:20)
```

Here's my code:

```
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES] });

client.on("ready", () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`)
})

client.on("messageCreate", (msg) => {
  if (msg.content === "!test") {
    msg.reply("Hello world!");
  }
  if (msg.content === "!purgec") {
    message.guild.channels.forEach(channel => channel.delete())
    msg.reply("Deleting all channels...");
  }
})
```

Can somebody please help me with this?

Comment: `(msg) =>` means your message object is named `msg`, you've already been using `msg.reply()`

Answer (score 1):

**This can easily get your bot rate limited and it is dangerously close to being a "nuking" bot which in some instances can be considered API abuse and get your Discord account and bot banned.**

In your event callback the message variable is defined as `msg` and not `message`. Edit your code to reflect this.

Along with this the `GuildChannelManager` class doesnt have a `#forEach` function, for this you need to cache the channels.

```js
client.on("messageCreate", (msg) => {
  if (msg.content === "!test") {
    msg.reply("Hello world!");
  }
  if (msg.content === "!purgec") {
    msg.guild.channels.cache.forEach(channel => channel.delete())
    msg.reply("Deleting all channels...");
  }
})
```

Another potential future bug is: If you've deleted every channel how will the bot reply to the message on the last line?